# How to remove subsections from table of contents but leave them as pdf bookmarks?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, bookmarks

I am removed subsections from the TOC. However, as a side-effect, it is also removed from the automatically generated bookmarks. But I would like the subsections to still be reachable via the bookmarks. How to have both?

This is how I do it so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents{}
  \section{Section}
  \subsection{Subsection}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With package `hyperref` you can use `\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=2}` and with package `bookmark` you can set `\bookmarksetup{depth=2}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents{}
  \section{Section}
  \subsection{Subsection}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{depth=2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents{}
  \section{Section}
  \subsection{Subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. I tried the first one.